# Inverse of a triangular matrix of special form

Tags: matrices, inverse

How should I begin when I want to get an inverse matrix from this one?

[image]

#### Progress

I have tried to do it explicitly for small $n$. But now I am not able to deduce the general pattern with $n$  from it. And even if I were able to, then I would have to prove that it is valid somehow.

Comment: Have you tried doing it explicitly for small values of $n$?

Comment: As already noted, try inverting smaller matrices. The pattern is obvious.

Comment: Yes, I have... But now I am not able to deduce the general pattern with 'n's from it... And even if I were able to, then I would have to prove that it is valid somehow... :-/

Answer (score 1):

One can also derive it directly knowing the inverse of a simpler matrix. Denote the original one by $A$ and let $P$ be the permutation so that $AP$ is upper triangular ($P$ is a flipped identity). Now with $D=\mathrm{diag}(1,\ldots,n)$ we get
$$\tag{1}
D^{-1}AP=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  &   & \ddots & \vdots \\
  &   &        & 1
\end{bmatrix}=:S.
$$
The inverse of the "partial summation" matrix $S$ is the well-known "difference" matrix:
$$
S^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 &        &        & \\
  &  1 & - 1    &        & \\
  &    & \ddots & \ddots & \\
  &    &        & \ddots & -1 \\
  &    &        &        & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So
$$
A^{-1}=PS^{-1}D^{-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it as a product of

$$\mathop{\rm diag}(1,2,3,\ldots n)\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1& \cdots 1\\ 1& 1&\cdots 0\\ \vdots\\ 1&0&\cdots 0\end{bmatrix}$$
The diagonal matrix is trivial to invert. The second matrix is just order-reversed discrete integration (cummulative summation) matrix, where differences between neighbouring rows give the result (the inverse is the discrete difference matrix).